# Почему игнорируется replace()?

Tags: java, парсер, формулы

Есть метод:

```
     public String getArgument (String partOfformula){

    partOfformula.toLowerCase();

    String firstArgument = "";
    String secondArgument ="";

    if (partOfformula.contains("(")){
       int startParseIndex=partOfformula.indexOf('(');
       int endParseIndex = partOfformula.indexOf(')');
       for (int i =startParseIndex+1; i < endParseIndex; i++){
           char ch = partOfformula.charAt(i);
           firstArgument = firstArgument.concat("r"+ch);
           if (ch==','){
               startParseIndex= partOfformula.indexOf(ch);
               for(int j =startParseIndex; j<endParseIndex; j++){
                   secondArgument.concat("r"+partOfformula.charAt(j));
               }
           }
       }
    };

   firstArgument.replace("r", "");
   return firstArgument;
  }
```

}

В нем я пытаюсь распарсить часть формулы, введенной пользователем и получить аргументы.

Например, если пользователь ввел `"sin (30)"` то метод должен вернуть `"30"`, однако IntelIJ пишет, что

> Result of firstArgument.replace ("r", "") is ignored!

и метод возвращает строку `"r3r0"`Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace` не меняет строку, относительно которой вызывается, а возвращает новую строку - измененную, если замена произошла, или такую же, если - нет.

```
firstArgument = firstArgument.replace("r", "");
```